# Vim delete buffer only when another buffer is deleted

Tags: vim, neovim, autocmd

I've configured Vim to look like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| N  |              Code             |
| E  |                               |
| R  |                               |
| D  |                               |
| T  |                               |
| r  |-------------------------------|
| e  |              REPL             |
| e  |                               |
+------------------------------------+
```

Every element is in it's own buffer. Is it possible to delete the REPL buffer only when I quit the code buffer? If I open and close help, for example, the REPL should stay but when I close the code buffer, the REPL buffer should close as well.
This is what I have now:

```
let s:code_repl_nrs = {} " A map of (code buffer number) - (REPL buffer number)
let s:last_leaved_buffer_nr = -1 " The number of the last leaved buffer

autocmd BufLeave,BufDelete * let s:last_leaved_buffer_nr = bufnr('%')
autocmd BufUnload * call <SID>StopREPL(s:last_leaved_buffer_nr) " Stop the REPL when closing the code buffer

"" Stops a REPL given the number of the current buffer
function! s:StopREPL(buffer_nr)
    let l:repl_nr = get(s:code_repl_nrs, a:buffer_nr . '', -1) " Get the number of the REPL buffer
    if l:repl_nr != -1
        exec l:repl_nr . 'bdelete!'
    endif
endfunction
```

When I use `:h`, the REPL closes. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `<abuf>` is the answer, replacing `s:last_leaved_buffer_nr`:

```
autocmd BufUnload * call <SID>StopRepl(expand('<abuf>'))
```

---

As per `:h <abuf>`:

> When executing autocommands, is replaced with the currently
> effective buffer number (for ":r file" and ":so file" it is
> the current buffer, the file being read/sourced is not in a
> buffer).

Turns out `<abuf>` gets expanded to the buffer number of the buffer that is currently unloading. When the code buffer is unloading, the buffer number will be in `s:code_repl_nrs` and `s:StopREPL` will be able to delete the REPL buffer. When some other buffer is unloading, `s:StopREPL` will not be able to delete the REPL buffer.